# Determine if a Point is in a 3D Cube

Tags: c#, point

I need the best possible solution, and if possible not dirty code, but rather some smart code.

I am not familiar with 3D programming.

I have to write a function that will return if a point is in 3D space (x, y, z). The range of the cube in space will be supplied (e.g. range { {1,2,1}, {5,6,4} })

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought through the problem? How, for instance, would you determine that the x-coordinate satisfies that single axis?

Comment: Is this homework? Thats not so much of a pronblem, but dont expect full "smart" code. A pointer in the right direction will help you more.

Comment: If you are not familiar with 3D programming, I guess you either find (and pay) someone who is or learn it by yourself.

Comment: Should I possibly handle it as a set of flat rectangles?

Comment: Solve it in 2D. Once you know how to do that, solving it in 3D should be trivial.

Comment: No not homework. I was asked to write a function. I am a developer but have almost never done 3D development. Pointer in the right direction will help.

Comment: You solve this by projecting to a lower dimension space. For example, when checking if a point is inside a rectangle, you project the width and the height to your reference axis as two *linear* bounded intervals and check if the point's coordinates are inside both intervals; that is, you are reducing a 2D problem to 2 1D problems. Solving the 3D problem is similar; you need to solve 2 2D problems (the 3rd check is redundant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to test whether the given point has all coordinates lying to between the points. So if (x1, y1, z1) is the minimum corner and (x2, y2, z2) is the max point, to test the point (x, y, z), verify that x1 <= x <= x2, and similarly for y and z.

If this doesn't seem obvious, just realize that a cube aligned with the coordinate axes is the region lying right of the plane x = x1, and left of the plane x = x2, above the plane y = y1 and below y = y2, etc. The points in the cube are those that satisfy all six inequalities simultaneously. This is precisely what you are verifying.

If the cube is not aligned with the coordinate axes you cannot determine it from two corners. Rather, it is described by giving inequalities for the planes that determine the six faces. You would need to check that all six are satisfied. This can always be written as a matrix inequality.  In this case, a 6x3 matrix: three columns since the points are in 3d space and one row for each constraint. This is the general case, but is overkill for the problem as stated.

Comment: Hmmmm. Might work. I understood that one could use matrices but man my mathematics are rusted

Comment: Yes, you can use matrices, but that is overkill. If your cube is always aligned with the coordinate planes, then this solution is correct as the cube is the set of points whose x coordinate is between x1 and x2 and y coordinates is between y1 and y2, etc.

Comment: Just be careful with signs - for example, if P1 is (-10, 10, -10) and P2 is (10, -10. 10)

Comment: Those are the "wrong corners" to use, yes. You need the minimum corner (bottom left so to speak) and the maximum corner (too right).

Comment: You can form the needed points by choosing the first one as the minimum of all pairs of values and the second as the max values.

Comment: It looks like the cube *will* be aligned with the coordinate axes, since the OP specifies the cube with just two opposite corners (which really defines a rectangular cuboid rather than specifically a cube, but of course this approach will work with a rectangular cuboid too).

Answer (score 1):

A point `p = (x, y, z)` is inside the cube with the extends `[x_0, x_1] x [y_0, y_1] x [z_0, z_1]` when each of the point's coordinates is within the respective ranges for x,y and z. That is in Pseudocode

```
  bool PointIsInCube( Point3D p, float x_max, float x_min, float y_max, float y_min, float z_max, float z_min)
  {
        return (p.x <= x_max && p.x >= x_min) && (p.y <= y_max && p.y >= y_min) && (p.z <= z_max && p.z >= z_min);
  }
```

With your given cube the intervals would be [1,5]x[2,6]x[1,4] if I have read that correctly. (first interval for x, second for y, third for z)

Answer (score 0):

For example you can calculate 3 projection(for each of axes).
For example if you want to have a projection for Z axe you can just erase Z-value from your point coordinates:

```
 projection({1,2,3}) -> {1,2}
```

And then just determine is projection(point) inside square which is also just a projection of bottom(or top) 4 points.
Ans the same for ather axes.